# Nginx: SSL certificate based on country

Tags: ssl, nginx

our web application is hosted on `.com` domain, but is used in different countries. The application runs on simple SSL certificate, but we consider using EV certificate. In each country we have a different local company, so we think about having EV certificate for each country.

Is it possible for `nginx` to serve different SSL EV certificate based on either location by IP address or at least by path in URL (`/en/home/`, `/it/...`, `/fr/...`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The best way that I know of to serve different certs from a single Nginx instance is by domain name.  (In theory it is possible to send different certs based on client IP but I do not think Nginx supports this functionality.  It is not possible to use URL paths because SSL negotiation occurs before the path is transmitted.)

Let's say your site is www.example.com.  First, set up country- or region-specific subdomains like es.example.com, fr.example.com, etc.

You can then use the [geoip module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_geoip_module.html) to redirect traffic to the appropriate subdomain, as in [this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-nginx-as-a-global-traffic-director-on-debian-or-ubuntu).

Once this is set up, you can define different nginx server blocks for each subdomain, each with its own certificate.  This will use [SNI](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/configuring_https_servers.html) to determine the appropriate cert to serve during SSL negotiation based on the requested domain name.  You'll also need to include a default wildcard cert, since not all browsers support SNI.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you use its LUA backend with the ssl part, you can use `ssl_certificate_by_lua_block` to decide which certificate you want to expose based on data sent by the client, like its IP address, look at the `raw_client_addr` function.

You can not access anything related to the URL, since that is in the HTTP protocol whose data happens far later in the TLS exchange. At best, you can access the hostname (website name) that the client requests in the SNI part of the TLS handshake.

For all details: https://github.com/openresty/lua-resty-core/blob/master/lib/ngx/ssl.md and https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module/#ssl_certificate_by_lua_block

Some snippets:

> ```
> ssl_certificate_by_lua_block
> ```
>
> syntax: ssl_certificate_by_lua_block { lua-script }
>
> This directive runs user Lua code when NGINX is about to start the SSL
>   handshake for the downstream SSL (https) connections.
>
> It is particularly useful for setting the SSL certificate chain and
>   the corresponding private key on a per-request basis.

And:

> ```
> raw_client_addr
> ```
>
> syntax: addr_data, addr_type, err = ssl.raw_client_addr()
>
> Returns the raw client address of the current SSL connection.
>
> The first two return values are strings representing the address data
>   and the address type, respectively. The address values are interpreted
>   differently according to the address type values:
>
> ```
> unix : The address data is a file path for the UNIX domain socket.
> inet : The address data is a binary IPv4 address of 4 bytes long.
> inet6 : The address data is a binary IPv6 address of 16 bytes long.
> ```

and for the website name:

> ```
> server_name
> ```
>
> syntax: name, err = ssl.server_name()
>
> context: any
>
> Returns the TLS SNI (Server Name Indication) name set by the client.
>   Returns nil when the client does not set it.
>
> In case of failures, it returns nil and a string describing the error.
>
> Usually we use this SNI name as the domain name (like
>   www.openresty.org) to identify the current web site while loading the
>   corresponding SSL certificate chain and private key for the site.